# How to return the array after altering it back into json format?

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, loops, discord.js

I am making a discord bot where you can use the command `tcp freeitem` to obtain your free item.
I am trying to alter that value of an Account by adding a new item object into the account. When I map the array to replace a value, it erases the name (allAccounts) of the array of the json. More information below. Here is what I have:

```
const listOfAllItemNames = require(`C:/Users///censored///OneDrive/Desktop/discord bot/itemsDataList.json`)
        const accountList = require(`C:/Users///censored///OneDrive/Desktop/discord bot/account.json`)
        const fs = require('fs')



       var accountThatWantsFreeItem = accountList.allAccounts.find(user => message.author.id === user.userId);
       var randomFreeItem = listOfAllItemNames.allItems[Math.floor(Math.random() * listOfAllItemNames.allItems.length)]

       
          
       if(accountThatWantsFreeItem === undefined) {message.reply('You need to make an account with tcp create!'); return; }
       if(accountThatWantsFreeItem.freeItem === true) {message.reply('You already got your free one item!'); return;}
       
       
       
       fs.readFile('C:/Users///censored///OneDrive/Desktop/discord bot/account.json', 'utf8', function readFileCallback(err,data) {

            if(err){
                console.error(err)

            } else {
            

            var accountsArray = JSON.parse(data)

            console.log(accountsArray)

            var whoSentCommand = accountsArray.allAccounts.find(user => message.author.id === user.userId)

                whoSentCommand.Items.push(randomFreeItem)
                
                whoSentCommand.freeItem = true;

            var test = accountsArray.allAccounts.map(obj => whoSentCommand === obj.id || obj)

           //I believe the issue is trying to map it returns a new array
             
            console.log(test)

            test = JSON.stringify(test, null, 5)
           
            //fs.writeFile('C:/Users///censored///OneDrive/Desktop/discord bot/account.json', test, err =>{  console.error(err)} )

            }



        })
```

when I write the file back to json file, it removes the "allAccounts" identifier in this file

```
//json file 
//array name "allAccounts" is removed, I need this still here for code to work
 {
     "allAccounts" : [
          {
               "userId": "182326315813306368",
               "username": "serendipity",
               "balanceInHand": 0,
               "balanceInBank": 0,
               "freeItem": false,
               "Items": []
          },
```

(No "allAccounts" array name)
to this: [output after writing file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJmHL.png)

So, the final question is
**How would I alter the array so that I only alter the account I want without editing the array name?**

Please feel free to ask any questions if I was unclear.

Comment: edit: here is the output : https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJmHL.png

Answer (score 2):

Array.map() method returns the converted array.
So in the below line, map() method takes allAccounts array and perform actions and put the target array (not object) to the test variable.

```
var test = accountsArray.allAccounts.map(obj => whoSentCommand === obj.id || obj)
```

So for making code works, please change the code like this:

```
var test = {
  "accountsArray": accountsArray.allAccounts.map(obj => whoSentCommand === obj.id || obj)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When posting questions, please please reduce the code to a minimal example that will demonstrate the problem, and use words, not code, to describe the problem.

It looks like you are expecting `.map` to do something other than what it does.

#### Please consult [the documentation for `Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

It takes the array that you pass it (in this case `accountsArray.allAccounts`) and transforms it, returning the transformed array.

You have essentially done `test = accountsArray.allAccounts` but for some reason are expecting `test` to contain an `Object` with the key `allAccounts`, when in fact it will only contain an `Array`, because that is what you have assigned it.